# Get Parent and grand parents of a particular child

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

i have  table like below

tablename :`ExampleTable`

```
ChildID       ChildCommonID   ParentID


1               2                0

2               3                0

3               4                1

4               5                3

5               6                4
```

The Problem is :

i have a child id example :`ChildID= 5`

so i need to check wheather it has a parent or not if it contain a parent 
then check the corresponsing parentid, in this case the parentID is 4 so need to check 
the child 4 has any parent ,in this case parentID of child 4 is 3, so gain check child 3 has any parent 
in this case child 3 has parent 1, so check child 1 has any parents here child 1 is the top grand parent and it has no parent so stop the process 
and return all childids up to 1

Here the expected output is

```
ChildID

5
4
3
1
```

i had tried something like below but it does not give correct output

```
with getallparent as (
   select * 
   from ExampleTable 
   where ChildID  = 5 
  union all 
  select *
   from ExampleTable c 
     Left join getallparent p on p.ChildID = c.ParentID 
) 
select *
from getallparent;
```

If you need the sample  data you can use the below query

```
create table ExampleTable(ChildID int,ChildCommonID int ,ParentID int )
insert into ExampleTable values(1,2,0)
insert into ExampleTable values(2,3,0)
insert into ExampleTable values(3,4,1)
insert into ExampleTable values(4,5,3)
insert into ExampleTable values(5,6,4)
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: your columns were incorrect in join. use `getallparent p on p.ParentID  = c.ChildID`. Also left join is not required

Comment: @ughai sure let me try that

Comment: @RoyiNamir i hope the question that you are provide as duplicate is different that question only takes the top parent and here i need total hierarchy

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV removed the dup.

Comment: @RoyiNamir thanks for your help .please help me to solve my problem  if you can

Comment: @ughai  i had tried that but it does not give the desired output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like my comment, your columns were incorrect in join. Use `getallparent p on p.ParentID = c.ChildID`.

```
with getallparent as (
   select ChildID,ParentID
   from ExampleTable 
   where ChildID  = 5 
  union all 
  select C.ChildID,C.ParentID
   from ExampleTable c 
     inner join getallparent p on p.ParentID = c.ChildID 
) 
select *
from getallparent;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/82032/3)

Comment: hei thanks man , silly mistake but it kills my 1 hour , your solution is working fine .thanks

Comment: I hope OP doesnt represent top leaf as `0 -> 0` becuase adding `(0, 2, 0);` will crash the query

Comment: @RoyiNamir childid will not be 0 , so i thing the query is safe ,is it ??

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV  as long as child id != parentID  , yes.

Comment: @RoyiNamir yes ,childid = parentid  will not apper